# Linux Gurobi LD_LIBRARY_PATH Unsatisfied link error AWS

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, amazon-web-services, gurobi

I've been working on installing/building up my linux ubuntu server on the Gurobi Cloud EC2 Instance, however i've been facing many obstacles. As of now i'm still trying to solve the LD_LIBRARY_PATH issue as it system still throws me java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no GurobiJni60 in java.library.path exception even if i run the java examples (make run_java) in the SSHed command line into my server.

I've set all my pathing in the .bashrc in my home directory as per the following :

```
export GUROBI_HOME="/opt/gurobi600/linux64"
export PATH="${PATH}:${GUROBI_HOME}/bin"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:${GUROBI_HOME}/lib".
```

I am currently also trying to install tomcat on the same server and trying to get it to work too. I've been stuck on this issue for a couple of days and am at wits end.
I would really appreciate it if someone could assist me in solving is issue.

Brandon